# how to pass data from one endpoint to another on the same page

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to display transactions of a wallet basing on the wallet id returned from the end point used to create the wallet but have failed to get away to pass the wallet id to the second end point for use.
Below is code, any help on how to can arrange my code and then pass the wallet  id is highly appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    wallets: [],
    transactions: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const temp = localStorage.getItem("data")
    const loadedData = JSON.parse(temp)
    const token = "Bearer " + loadedData.token
    const userId = {
      "user_id": loadedData.user_id
    }
    const requiredOptions1 = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userId),
    }
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9000/user_wallet_details", requiredOptions1)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({ wallets: res });
    });


    const walletId = {
      "wallet_id": wallet_id
    }
    const requiredOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(walletId),
    }
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9000/transaction_base_on_wallet", requiredOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      
    });


  }
```

Comment: wallet_id seems to be undefined. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use useParams() for this problem.
Just pass the walletID in the link path. and use useParams() on the second Page to extract the wallet ID from the url.

for Example:-
On First Page pass the argument in path like,
`` <Link to=`/resultPage/${walletID}`>Click Me</Link> ``

On the Result Page, extract the walletID using,
`const walletID = useParams();`

To extract the variable from the Path, declare the Route path as,
`<Route path="/resultPage/:walletID" element="<HomePage />" />`